# How to set UserDetails in LdapAuthenticationProvider Spring Security?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I've got my Spring MVC application in which I use LDAP for authentication and MySQL database for authorization. There is ldap-config.xml file below.

```
<bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
    <property name="url" value="ldap://myLdapServerIp" />
    <property name="base" value="ou=people,dc=company,dc=int" />
</bean>

<bean id="ldapAuthProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
            <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
            <property name="userDnPatterns">
                <list>
                    <value>uid={0}</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean id="authorities" class="com.package.security.MyLDAPAuthorities">
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationManager"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <constructor-arg ref="ldapAuthProvider" />
</bean>
```

And class MyLDAPAuthorities simply gets roles from database.

```
@Service
public class MyLDAPAuthorities implements LdapAuthoritiesPopulator {

@Autowired
UserDao userDao;

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(
        DirContextOperations userData, String username) {

    User user= userDao.findUserByName(username);
    Collection<Role> userPermission = user.getRoles();
    Collection<MyGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Role r : userPermission){
        authorities.add(new MyGrantedAuthority(r.getPk().getRole().toString()));
    }
    return authorities;
}
```

}

This works fine but i would like to add some other staff from database to User(Principal?) bean and be able to use this data in my web application in any time. I suppose I should implement UserDetailsService and connect it with Spring but although I read quite a lot, I don't know how to do it in my case. Maybe my approach is wrong and I should change it completely? Thanks in advance for any help or tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to follow the instructions in the manual on [using a `UserDetailsContextMapper` with LDAP](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ldap-custom-user-details).

Since you want to call the database here, I would use a [`NullLdapAuthoritiesPolulator`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ldap/authentication/NullLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.html) and just load all the data, including the user roles, in your `UserDetailsContextMapper`. That way you'll avoid having to make two database calls.